# c# splitting and retrieving values from a string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this:

```
"http://localhost:55164/Images/photos/2/2.jpg"
```

I need to retrieve the filename and the 2 out of the `/2/` and put them into their own strings. I've been messing around with `StringBuilder` and replace and substr to no avail since the filename length is variable.  Anyone have a quick way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Regex with groups, or you could split by "/"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string link = "http://localhost:55164/Images/photos/2/2.jpg"; // your link
string[] x = link.Split('/'); // split it into pieces at the slash
string filename = (x.Length >= 1) ? x[x.Length - 1] : null; // get the last part
string dir = (x.Length >= 2) ? x[x.Length - 2] : null; // get the 2nd last part
```

**Edit**, checked the array length before trying to access it's pieces like someone suggested below in the comments.

Comment: Note: in real life, you'd actually check the length of x rather than blindly assuming you have at least 2 elements.

Comment: @David Kemp thanks, overlooked that fact. fixed it now though.

Answer (score 1):

You could cheat and use the `Path` class. This is easier and adds extra readability at the same time.

```
string path = "http://localhost:55164/Images/photos/2/2.jpg";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(path));
string[] dirSplit = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Split('\\');
Console.WriteLine(dirSplit[dirSplit.Length - 1]);
```

Comment: umm nice, did not know about the path class before. I like the first part, but seems a bit redundant to use it (and) split the string, when splitting can achieve both things.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `Path` class:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(s);
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(s).GetFileName(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Split function with '/' as separator and take 2 last elements of the array.

```
            string s = "";
            string[] arr = s.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string ans = "";
            if (arr.Length > 1)
                ans = arr[arr.Length - 1] + arr[arr.Length - 2];
```

Answer (score 0):

One quick way you could do with would be to split the string by the forward slash.

In this way you'll know that the last item in the array and the second-to-last item will be what you require.

Such that:

```
string url = "http://localhost:55164/Images/photos/2/2.jpg";
string[] urlParts = url.Split('/');
string file = urlParts[urlParts.length -1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class which is tailor-made for this purpose (providing easy access to parts of a URI), e.g.,

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:55164/Images/photos/2/2.jpg");
string[] segments = uri.Segments;
foreach (string segment in segments)
{
    Console.WriteLine(segment.Trim('/'));
}
```